# Como leer un div anidado sin que tenga clase definida

Tags: php, codeigniter

estoy con el siguiente problema con un scrapper, tengo el siguiente codigo

```
    $text = get_content_of_element($html, 'div', 'class', 'text');
```

y el sitio donde necesito leer los datos tiene la siguiente estructura

```
<div class="text">
            <div style="estilos declarados">
                <div style="imagen aca"></div>

            <div><h3 style="font:18px arial, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; padding:10px 0;">Overview</h3></div>
            <div>recien aca el texto que quiero leer</div><br>
            <div>texto que me gustaria eliminar</b></a></div>
        <div></div></div>
```

se les ocurre alguna manera de leer el el dato que necesito? se puede pasar como parametro que lea recien el 5º div? y en ese caso tambien dentro del texto puedo borrar el "div" 6º ?

muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP tiene clases para leer HTML... Considerando que tu HTML sea correcto y no tenga errores:

```html
<div class="text">
  <div style="estilos declarados">
    <div style="imagen aca"></div>
    <div><h3 style="font:18px arial, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; padding:10px 0;">Overview</h3></div>
    <div>recien aca el texto que quiero leer</div><br>
    <div>texto que me gustaria eliminar</div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ejecutaríamos lo siguiente:

```
 $DOM = new DOMDocument;
 $DOM->loadHTML($string_con_el_html);
 $divs = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('div');

 print_r($divs[4]->textContent);
```

Porque contando los `DIV` que están anidando el texto que buscas está en la posición #5 y dado que los `array` se cuentan desde 0 tu elemento es el #4.